# Fixing merge conflicts when merging to one branch, messes up commit on another branch

Tags: git, github

I have `develop`, `master` and a `feature` branch.

I made some changes on the `feature` branch and I made a PR on `master`. I also made a PR on `develop` which has changes that are not on the `master` branch.

It turned out that when I wanted to make PR on `develop` I had some conflicts so I fixed them on Github.

But what this basically did, was that `develop` was merged on my `feature` branch, and now my PR on `master` branch has all these commits from `develop` branch.

And I don't need that.

I tried using `git revert` but that didn't do anything on my `feature` branch.

Is there a way to remove this merge from the `feature` branch, or should I just close this PR and create a separate branch?

Branches look like this:

```
--------------master
  |     |
  |-----|-----------develop
        |------feature
```

I merged from `master` and made PR on `develop` and `master` from `feature` branch.

Not sure how I got the conflict, but `develop` branch has tons of stuff on it.

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem, though I will say that the best solution would be to fix your workflow such that you don't end up in this situation.  Maybe you can add a branch diagram here which will show your current state.

Comment: I added the graph and some additional explation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your workflow is a little more complicated / less linear than typical.  That's not necessarily bad if it meets your needs, but you might want to see if something more structured (like gitflow) might *also* meet your needs, while making sure that most of the problems you face (and their solutions) are things more people will have experience with.

(While you're using some terms from gitflow, in gitflow you would not merge a feature directly to `master`.  Of course you could have a hotfix from time to time, and those would merge directly to both `master` and `develop`, but in that case you'd probably merge to `master` first, knowing that (a) that's where the hotfix branch was split from, and (b) everything in `master` is already in `develop`.)

All of the above is fine and good, but for now you are where you are, and anyway you might look at it and decide that your workflow is the best one for your project... so how do you make this work?

So if I understand, you had

```
 A -- M <--(master)
     /   
... B -- C -- D <--(develop)

... E -- F <--(feature)
```

and you created a PR to integrate `feature` into `develop`, but there were conflicts - and to resolve those conflicts while allowing for review before `develop` would be updated, the resolution process merged into `feature`

```
 A -- M <--(master)
     /   
... B -- C -- D <--(develop)
               \
  ... E -- F -- X <--(feature)
```

There are many ways to fix this, but I'm going to assume that in your situation it'd be best to avoid history rewrites (i.e. avoid removing commits from the history of any published branch).

In that case, the simplest way forward is to create a new branch at `F` for the PR into `master`.

```
git checkout feature^
git branch feature_b
```

Comment: The flow that we use is: First we create a `develop` branch. Then we create various `feature` branches, and merge them to `develop`. Once we are ready to move to production, we merge `develop` to `master`. After production, we create `feature` branches from the `master` branch, and we make a PR's to `develop` (which is our staging where we test the features), and when everything is done, we create a PR to `master` branch. But when I tried to resolve conflicts the `develop` was merged to my `feature` branch. In the end, I created a new branch and a new PR to `master` to avoid that. Thanks